# How can two people have separate accounts on the same browser?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Like the title says.  Is this possible?  If not, why not?  If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Sure, just log out. Even a *single* person can have multiple accounts, as long as they use them for legitimate purposes. (Am I missing some nuance here?)

Comment: if both accounts want to logon on the same browser simultaneously, this info might be useful for you: http://justtechnika.com/articles/login-to-multiple-accounts-in-same-website-simultaneously-at-the-same-time/

Comment: @Tim: I have deleted my answer. Thanks for your explanation there.

Comment: Yes, but neither can log in using Google accounts.  It only takes the first one.

Answer (score 8):

Both people will have to register for an account (using different openIDs).  Each user will have to log out when they are finished with their session.

When I've dealt with this before, I usually created a separate computer account (windows user) and that way they had to log out of their windows account, but they had their own bookmarks and cookies, and didn't have to log in to their various websites again.

Another alternative is to install Safari, Chrome, or Firefox and have one person use one browser, and the other use a different browser.

Comment: The "two browsers" is usually the path of least friction - I use Opera, my wife uses FF, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution if using Firefox is to create two profiles inside Firefox, and switch between them with [ProfileSwitcher extension](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/profileswitcher-en.html).

Edit: from @xport question's comment Multifox does the same and seems easier.

Comment: This sounds like the simplest.